# How to run nightwatch.js tests in parallel?

Tags: testing, parallel-processing, nightwatch.js, web-testing

I came across this question: 
[How can I run multiple tests in parallel with JS/nightwatchjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271495/how-can-i-run-multiple-tests-in-parallel-with-js-nightwatchjs)

But I want to execute multiple tests in parallel in the chrome browser only, in multiple chrome driver sessions.

I am used to java-testng-selenium based test suites where I can specify in the testng.xml file that I want to run multiple test classes or test methods in parallel and the framework does that exactly. If I specify in testng.xml that I want multiple test methods to execute in parallel in 4 threads, 4 chrome browser sessions pop-up and 4 test methods are executed in parallel.

Here's an example with a thread-count=2: https://github.com/adityai/testng-parallelsample/blob/master/methods-test-testng.xml

How can I do the same with nightwatch.js?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [`test_workers`](https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/) configuration, although I haven't tried it myself it should do exactly what you are looking for.

And a nice article that demostrates it in action:
https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/speeding-up-nightwatch-powered-acceptance-tests/

Comment: That is a really good article. It answers my question and I learned so much more out of it.

Comment: Glad it helped, could you mark the answer as completed? @AdityaInapurapu

Comment: It is a good article, but I keep getting 'expression expected' errors in globals.js as described in that article. I committed that code to a branch named 'selenium-less' in this github repo: https://github.com/adityai/nightwatch-sample

Comment: Additionally, I've had this json in my nightwatch.json file before I saw this article. It still does not run the tests in parallel.
{
    "test_workers": {
        "enabled": true,
        "workers": "auto"
      }
}

Comment: @AdityaInapurapu could you post the errors you are getting?

Comment: @AdityaInapurapu there is at least one issue that I spotted in your json and that is where you have the `test_workers` setting. It should be in the top level.
https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/